# Image will not display using localhost

Tags: html, image, localhost

I have set up a local web server on my desktop PC with Windows 10 and can display a web page with text, but images will not display?

I can access the website using http://localhost/test/index.asp

Both index.asp and btnCancel.gif are in the root directory.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Website</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<br>
Testing Localhost website<br>
<img src="btnCancel.gif">
</body>
</html>
```

The 'Testing Localhost website' text displays OK, but the btnCancel.gif image will not display.

I expected to see the text and the Cancel button?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think `http://localhost/` is the root, but you're in the `http://localhost/test` directory. That's not what you're saying though, so I'm not sure. But try adding a slash to the start of the image's name. The slash will definitely look in the root.

```
<img src="/btnCancel.gif">
```

Comment: I'm working in a /Test/ directory off the root, //localhost. I'm afraid that /btnCancel.gif didn't work.